# A phonetic Vowelburger™ Riddle

Tags: word, wordplay, language, english, letters

*<sup>You can find the other Vowelburger™ Riddles [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=vowelburger+is%3Aquestion)</sup>*
I ordered 5 Vowelburgers™ with buns and meat only at the **linguistic restaurant** - help me identify each one from the description on the menu!

The buns are [pulmonic consonants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_pulmonic_consonant_chart_with_audio) and the meat is a [vowel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio), so the transcription of the Vowelburgers™ may not share the same consonants.

| Meat | Vowelburger™ |
| --- | --- |
| ??? | graveyard |
| ??? | aggregate |
| ??? | card |
| ??? | look |
| ??? | states |

You can write your answer using IPA or the English alphabet as you please; bon appétit!

Comment: In case it matters, do you assume a rhotic or non-rhotic accent? (For example, does a word like "card" have two consonants or three?)

Comment: It does not mattA :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the buns are

> [S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolar_fricative#Voiceless_alveolar_sibilant) and [M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_bilabial_nasal)

graveyard

> CEM (short for cemetry)

aggregate

> SUM

card

> SIM

look

> SEEM (the vowel here is [i](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_front_unrounded_vowel))

states

> SAM (as in [Uncle Sam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncle_Sam))

Comment: Argh. Nicely done. I got this word for "aggregate", but couldn't figure out the other words to fit.

Comment: @randalthor wait for the next one then

Answer (score 3):

I think

> the first consonant is /s/ and the second one is /z/

and the words are:

*graveyard*

> ???

*aggregate*

> SIZE

*card*

> ???

*look*

> SEES

*states*

> SAYS

Comment: Wow, the first time ever I've seen a wrong answer to a Vowelburger™ riddle! Thank you for the effort anyway, keep trying

Comment: @melfnt I had a few other guesses, mostly starting from "aggregate" (e.g. that word being MASS or SUM), but couldn't get them to work even as well as this one.